# How to use ngSwitch in angular2

Tags: angular

Since last two days I am trying to get `ngSwitch` to work in *Angular 2.1.0*. But it seems impossible to get it work.

I always get:

> No provider for NgSwitch

Below is my code:

Template:

```html
<template [ngSwitch]="buttonSelector">
  <a class="btn" [ngClass]="buttonSizeClass" *ngSwitchCase="'link'" href="#">
    <span class="btn__text">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </span>
  </a>
</template>
```

Component:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-inked-btn',
  templateUrl: './inked-btn.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inked-btn.component.css'],
  inputs: ['buttonSize', 'buttonType', "buttonSelector"]
})
export class InkedBtnComponent implements OnInit {
  public buttonSize: string;
  public buttonType: string;
  public buttonSelector: string;
  public buttonSizeClass: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buttonSizeClass = {
      'btn--lg': this.buttonSize === 'large',
      'btn--sm': this.buttonSize === 'small',
      'btn--primary': this.buttonType === 'primary'
    }
  }

}
```

Below is my module configuration:

```ts
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { InkedBtnComponent } from './inked-btn/inked-btn.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: [HeaderComponent, FooterComponent, InkedBtnComponent],
  exports: [HeaderComponent, FooterComponent, InkedBtnComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

This shared module is then imported in the main module.

Where is the miss?

Comment: have you imported BrowserModule?

Comment: @xe4me BrowserModule is imported in main module

Answer (score 35, accepted):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html

`ngSwitch` can't be on a `<template>` element, only on real elements like `<div>`

Only `ngSwitchCase` can be applied to `<template>` elements

```
<template [ngSwitchCase]="match_expression_3">
```

Alternatively since final `ng-container` can be used instead of `<template>` with the more common syntax:

```
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_3">
```

Comment: After changing tamplate to div I get below error - No provider for TemplateRef!

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in https://plnkr.co/edit/HkKZlnBnLHikk0ciAPVH?p=preview?

Comment: My bad. Its working fine. I used [ngSwitchCase] instaed of *ngSwitchCase.

Comment: A `*` before a directive makes Angular2 expand it to a `<template [directive]=...`> and therefore results to the same behavior as before. `*` is just syntactic shugar so you don't need to add `<template ...>` explicitly.

Comment: And I again can't be enough thankful for the wonderful logic and intuitivity of the angularjs. Not a big problem - I still use `[ngIf]`s, they are working also on templates, it is a pretty good workaround until around angular8.3.

Comment: `*ngSwitchCase` on `template` elements didn't work for me, had to use `ng-container` elements

Comment: If you have a `<template>` element, you need to use the canonical syntax `[ngSwitchCase]="expression"` instead of `*ngSwitchCase="expression"`

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `ngSwitch` from `angular2/common`

```
import {NgSwitch} from 'angular2/common'
```

Comment: I have imported the commonModule

Comment: Good idea if you want to minimize the imports, for example because some ngc incompatibility, or because tree shaking won't work so well as it was said in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Also facing the same issue Make sure

1. `NgSwitch` should not be no template it should be on real element like Div
2. `*ngSwitchCase="expression"` should be nested inside `NgSwitch` element