# Angular, using one component in other two components

Tags: angular

I want to use one component in another two components like that:

```
<jhi-articles-list-component [active]="true"></jhi-articles-list-component>
```

so i created some shared module and export that component like this:

```
@NgModule({
    exports: [ArticlesListComponent]
})
export class ArticlesListModule {}
```

And then im imported that module in modules that i want to use that component which causes the error:

> Can't export directive ArticlesListComponent from ArticlesListModule
>   as it was neither declared nor imported!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add some imports to that shared module like CommonModule and it works now.

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [ArticleSharingAppSharedLibsModule, ArticleSharingAppSharedCommonModule, 
   ArticleSharingAppAppRoutingModule],
   declarations: [ArticlesListComponent],
   exports: [ArticlesListComponent],
   schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],

})
export class ArticlesListModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add `declarations` :

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ArticlesListComponent],
    exports: [ArticlesListComponent]
})
export class ArticlesListModule {}
```

Comment: I get multiple template parse errors now, it works perfectly fine when i add that component in one of that modules like this:                                                declarations: [HomeComponent ArticlesListComponent],

Comment: What i meant was, import the `ArticlesListModule ` in your module where you have to use it and then `ArticlesListComponent` can be used there. what error do you get?

Comment: i'm doing exactly what you said, i get that error: https://ibb.co/P4BfCCH

Comment: @MaciejOstaszewski in your `ArticlesListModule ` try to : `import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';` and then add `CommonModule` to another array within `@NgModule` : `imports: [CommonModule ]`

Answer (score 0):

Your component (used at multiple places) should be declared and exported from it's module.

This will make it available in other modules and can be used once component's module (in this case: `ArticlesListModule` ) is imported:

```
    @NgModule({
       declarations: [ArticlesListComponent],
       exports: [ArticlesListComponent]
    })
    export class ArticlesListModule {}
```

Comment: @MaciejOstaszewski Did you import `ArticlesListModule`  and add it to `imports` array of `@NgModule`  of the module where you are using the component?

Comment: Yes i did it as you say

Comment: The error is with the way you use ngSwitch in HTML. ngSwitch can't be on a `<template>` element, only on real elements like `<div>`

Only ngSwitchCase can be applied to `<template>` elements. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41085168/9386929